# how to do administartive tasks from remote X SSH

Tags: remote-desktop, administration, policykit, x11-forwarding

I forwarded X over ssh. From unity-control-center I couldn't perform any of the administrative tasks like changing audio input, changing wifi network etc. How can I do them remotely. Its the same problem even when I connect through remote desktop. I think its some thing to do with policy kit. I could never remotely operate X since my introduction to ubuntu; Its 5yrs bck!

Answer (score 0):

There is probably a couple solutions for things you requested.

VNC-server. Client-server couple actually. Allows you to control remote screen directly, to the active screen of the remote machine.

NX-server. Again Client-server pair. Allows you to have connection to independent Desktop with GUI, separate/different from the main screen (which is shown at monitor)